# Plotting weighted nodes around a center

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to plot nodes around a central node dynamically by weights of similarity. I have the weight of each node to every other node. I need to display the arrangement in such a fashion that it portrays the similarity of each node to every other node. I want how similar a node is (say node $B$) to the central node to be how far the distance is from that particular node ($B$) to the central node while having the other nodes (say $C$ or $D$) to the have distance by the similarity (or weight) of $C$ to $B$ etc.

[image]

Here is an example of what I'm kind of going for. What is the best way to go about doing this mathematically?

Comment: Since you've tagged this [tag:graph-theory], you could try [force-directed graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing), but arranging nodes according to similarity is really more about [multidimensional scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling).

Comment: I don't believe there is a tag for that topic but thank you for putting me in the correct direction.